# search by type in php don´t working

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I had a program written in php. I want select a category and shows articles related. I select one category but dont show a articule. Anybody helps me?

catalogo.php

```
        <div class="col-md-4-fluid">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="buscartipo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="pull-right">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="tipo">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Buscar por tipo</option>
                        <option value="tecnologia">Llave T</option>
                        <option value="deportes">Herramientas especiales</option>
                        <option value="arte">Kit de puesta a punto</option>
                        <option value="viajes">Otros</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                     </span>  
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!--Fin row buscadores-->

    <!--Comienzo row ofertas-->

<div class="row" id="catalogo"> 
<?php
include "conexionnew.php";

    if(isset($_SESSION['empleado'])){
        $idempleado=$_SESSION['empleado']['id_usuario'];
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM empleado where id_usuario!='$id_usuario'");
        while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="example-image-link" href='<?php echo($array['imagen']);?>' data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Optional caption."><img class="example-image" src='<?php echo ($array['imagen']);?>' alt=""/></a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p><?php echo $array['descripcion'];?></p>
                        <h3><?php echo "$".$array['precio'];?></h3>
                        <?php echo "<p><a href='descripcion.php?id_plantilla=$array[id_plantilla]' class='btn btn-primary' role='button'>Comprar ahora</a></p>";?> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
        }
    }else{
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM articulo");
        while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="example-image-link" href='<?php echo($array['imagen']);?>' data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Optional caption."><img class="example-image" src='<?php echo ($array['imagen']);?>' alt=""/></a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p><?php echo $array['codarticulo'];?></p> 
                        <h3><?php echo "$".$array['precio'];?></h3>
                       <?php echo "<p><a href='descripcion.php?idarticulo=$array[idarticulo]' class='btn btn-primary' role='button'>Ver detalle</a></p>";?> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
        }
    }
?>              

    <!--Fin row ofertas-->
</div>
</div>
```

the values is received by buscartipo.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];

if(empty($tipo)){
    echo "<script>alert('Seleccione un tipo de plantilla')</script>";
    echo "<script>location.href='catalogo.php'</script>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Inicio | F y F herramientas</title>
        <!-- core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>

         <!-- para sweet alert2 -->
        <script src="bower_components/es6-promise/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script> <!-- for IE support -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
</head>
    <body class="homepage">
        <?php require_once('cabecera.php'); ?>      

        <section id="feature">
            <div class="container">
            <!--Container cabecera-->

                <div class="container" id="contenido-cabecera">
                    <div id="titulo-cabecera">Articulos</div>
                    <p>Filtrado por tipo</p>
                </div>

            <!--Fin Container cabecera-->

            <!--Comienzo container buscar por tipo-->           
                <div class="row" id="buscar-tipo">  
<?php
include "conexionnew.php";

/*$id_articulo=$_SESSION['articulo']['idarticulo'];          */ 
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM articulo where tipo='$tipo'");
while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    if($array['idarticulo']!=$id_articulo){
?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="example-image-link" href='<?php echo($array['imagen']);?>' data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Optional caption."><img class="example-image" src='<?php echo($array['imagen']);?>' alt=""/></a>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p><?php echo $array['descripcion'];?></p>
                    <h3><?php echo "$".$array['precio'];?></h3>
                    <?php echo "<p><a href='descripcion.php?id_plantilla=$array[id_plantilla]' class='btn btn-primary' role='button'>Comprar ahora</a> </p>";?> 
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<?php
        }

    }
?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!--Fin container buscar por tipo-->
        </section>  
<?php require_once('pie.php'); ?> 
</html>
```

Comment: post the relevant codes only so that it would be easier to sort out

Comment: Please explain which part of the code is not working, expected Vs. actual output etc.

Comment: this part of my code don´t working /*$id_articulo=$_SESSION['articulo']['idarticulo'];          */ 
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM articulo where tipo='$tipo'");
while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    if($array['idarticulo']!=$id_articulo){
?>

Comment: I want to show filtered result. The output don´t show articles